# Determine stable set via simultaneous stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control, stability-theory

Consider a system of n nonlinear ODE's $\dot{x} = f(x)$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, with only a few equilibrium points scattered around (The one in my mind right now is the [Kuramoto model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuramoto_model) ) Given an equilibrium point $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, I want to find the largest (or sufficiently large), open ball $B_{r}(x_{0})$ around $x_{0}$, such that if $x(t_{0}) \in B_{r}(x_{0})$, $d(x(t), x_{0}) < r$. Such a set is also known to be a stable set

I know a very fast way to verify simultaneous stability of a system of linear ODEs: $\dot{x_{i}} = A_{i}x_{i}$, $1\leq i\leq m$, determine if there exist $P \succ 0$, s.t. $A_{i}P+PA_{i}^{\top} \prec 0$ for all i.

> Now I heard that verifying whether a set(in this case an open ball) is stable or not can be turned into a simultaneous problem. However, I have thought about it for a while, but do not know how to proceed.

I think it has to do with the existence of a Lyapunov function V where $\{ x|V(x) < s \}$ is a stable set. However, I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

---

Edit: I asked and heard that to determine if a neighborhood N around $x_0$ is a stable set, we can verify whether there exists $P \succ 0$ s.t. $A_xP+PA_x^T \prec 0$ for all $x \in N$, where $A_x$ is the linearized approximation of the ODE at x. Assuming the $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable, I guess this is only a sufficient but not necessary condition. However, I'm not sure of the proof for the sufficient direction nor whether it is necessary.

Comment: Note that the "fast way to verify simultaneous stability of a system of linear ODEs" is only sufficient, not necessary. So if you find such $P$ then great, you can prove simultaneous stability, but there exist systems $\dot{x}_i=A_ix_i$ such that $x_i\rightarrow0$ for all $i,x_i(0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ but no $P\succ 0$ exists such that $A_i^TP+PA_i\prec 0$.

Comment: The condition you mentioned, which involves finding a matrix $P \succ 0$ such that $A_x^T P + P A_x \prec 0$ for all x in a neighborhood around the equilibrium point $x_0$, is indeed related to the stability of the system. This is known as the Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) condition. Do you mean the stability of LMI in ODE?

Comment: @YaoshengDeng Thank you for your comment. I am sorry that I'm unfamiliar with the LMI condition you are referring to and did not find much with a quick search. Mind sharing any sources you are aware of for that?

Comment: @YaoshengDeng Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with LMI, so can you elaborate on what you mean by "stability of LMI in ODE"? I am very sure, however, that I'm looking to verify for stable set, instead of stability at $x_0$.